# ASP NET MVC - ERRO DE “CORS”

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, http, cors

Olá,

Estou com um erro e não consigo corrigi-lo. Tenho uma aplicação ASP NET-MVC5 e nela carrego um frame na minha view que possui algumas fontes, porém elas estão dando o seguinte erro:

> Access to font at 'https://www.fontteste/fonts/Bold.woff' from origin 'http://localhost:62688' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Já coloquei no meu **"web.config**" o seguinte trecho, porém sem sucesso:

```
 <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
```

Poderiam me ajudar ?

Comment: Tenta alterar o arquivo `applicationHost.config` colocando seu customHeader que fica em uma pasta oculta do seu projeto: "Seu_Projeto\.vs\config\applicationhost.config"

Comment: Eu inclui, mas mesmo assim o erro permanece :(
`<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>

        <clear />
        <add name="X-Powered-By" value="ASP.NET" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT" />
      </customHeaders>
      <redirectHeaders>
        <clear />
      </redirectHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>`

Comment: Voce consegue adicionar mais detalhes (adicionar o controller e o html da sua pagina)? Vai ajudar a resposta final, mas, você ja tentou adicionar o pacote Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors e adicionar o atributo na sua controller [EnableCors]?

Answer (score 0):

No Global.asax, insira o cabeçalho no "Application_PreSendRequestHeaders"

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
{
     this.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
     this.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
}
```